# remove/subset or select columns based on a part of the header name

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe of 15000 obs. of 45 variables, with a similar structure/mode/class as the example input dataframe given below.

What I would like to do is select the "Date" column + columns containing "_MIN" as part of the header and put them into a new df. & select the "Date" column + columns containing "_MIN" as part of the header and put them into a new df.

So I am basically looking for **a way to select or subset whole columns based on a part of the name of the column header.** An example: *multiple columns contain a "_" underscore and I would like to delete or select these columns.*

```
INPUT dataframe:
Example <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("1979/1/1"),as.Date("1979/1/5"), by="day"), ca_MIN=1:5, ca_MAX=2:6, cb_MIN=3:7, cb_MAX=4:8)

>Example

    Date                  ca_MIN     ca_MAX     cb_MIN     cb_MAX
    1 1979-01-01          1          2          3          4
    2 1979-01-02          2          3          4          5
    3 1979-01-03          3          4          5          6
    4 1979-01-04          4          5          6          7
    5 1979-01-05          5          6          7          8

OUTPUT dataframes, selected based on the column names "_MAX", "_MIN":
Example_MIN <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("1979/1/1"),as.Date("1979/1/5"),     by="day"), ca_MIN=1:5, cb_MIN=3:7)
Example_MAX <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("1979/1/1"),as.Date("1979/1/5"), by="day"), ca_MAX=2:6, cb_MAX=4:8)

>Example_MIN

    Date            ca_MIN cb_MIN
  1 1979-01-01      1      3
  2 1979-01-02      2      4
  3 1979-01-03      3      5
  4 1979-01-04      4      6
  5 1979-01-05      5      7
```

At the moment it works with:

```
Example_MIN <-Example 
Example_MAX <-Example
subset(ExampleMIN,select=-c(2,4))
subset(ExampleMAX,select=-c(3,5))
```

This however gives me an error for the large dataset (although the outcome works for me):

```
Error in `[.data.table`(x, r, vars, with = FALSE) : j out of bounds
```

Is there a less cumbersome way to do this?

I would prefer it also to work with dataset with a large number of columns & with the column "_MIN" & "_MAX" not sorted as odd and even columnnumber?

I have seen post that are related, but I haven't managed this far to create a code that worked...

Comment: `Example[grepl("_MIN", names(Example))]` and `Example[grepl("_MAX", names(Example))]`

Comment: and from the error message it looks like a `data.table`. In that case `Example[, grepl("_MIN", names(Example)), with = F]`

Comment: @Ronak Shah. yes apparently somewhere in my script my data.frame turned into a data.table. That 's why my earlier attempts didn't work. Thanks for pointing that out. I will keep that in mind the next time I perform an operation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of ways to do this.

`grepl("_",names(Example)` will give you a list of trues and falses for those columns, so:

`Example[,grepl("_",names(Example)]` will give you the properly subset data.frame.

A more friendly way to do this is using dplyr:

`Example %>% select(contains("_"))`

an exercise for you is then going to be how to select those columns AND the date column. Hint for the base-R solution: `|` is OR and `&` is logical AND. Good luck!

Comment: I used 'Example.max <- Example[, grepl("_MAX", names(Example)), with = F]' & 'Example.max <- cbind(Example$Date,Example)'

Comment: Close... but you can do better... try to put both conditions into one... so `Example[,CONDITIONS]`. Where conditions are both the "_" and "date". Try... specifying multiple filters in one step is very important for your R skills. If you can't get it, I'll show u how. Also, do try the dplyr way... if you don't know dplyr, you should learn!

Comment: I have used the dplyr package before, but I can't  seem to combine the two functions. I am relatively new to R so i am probably working inefficient most of the time....
The dplyr package would use bind_cols in stead of cbind right? and maybe use select_if to slect the columns??

Comment: I already gave you the solution using dplyr... look again at my answer. Don't worry about being new to R... we are all new to R sometime. :) I recommend doing several dplyr tutorials... it's MUCH easier for beginners to learn than base R. Good luck! And don't be scared to ask me if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try grep on names, the trick is to do a proper $ref to the date column as well

```
Example_MIN <- Example[ , c(Example$Date, grep('_MIN', names(Example)))]
```

Comment: Generates the following error in my dataset: Error in grep("_MAX") : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 0):

U can use stringr package and choose from the vector of column names:

```
Example <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("1979/1/1"),as.Date("1979/1/5"), by="day"), ca_MIN=1:5, ca_MAX=2:6, cb_MIN=3:7, cb_MAX=4:8)
library(stringr)
# columns including MIN
chosenColumns <- str_detect(names(Example), "MIN")
#include also dates
chosenColumns[1] <- TRUE
mins <- Example[, chosenColumns]
```